# Как правильно закрыть окно Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть многооконное приложение. Виджеты иногда меняют родителей и переходят из одного окна в другое. Возникает необходимость закрывать окна с остатками виджетов. Например, было два окна, в каждом по два `QLabel`. Из одного окна в другое перешел `QLabel`. Окно с оставшимся в нем одним `QLabel` больше не нужно и его можно полностью удалить со всеми виджетами в нем. Как теперь правильно удалить это окно, чтобы не было утечек памяти и других неприятных вещей? Или память освобождается автоматически?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для каждого окна установите атрибут:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

Этот атрибут делает следующее:

> Makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close event (see QWidget::closeEvent()).

Другими словами, когда окно получает `QCloseEvent`, оно самоуничтожается

Comment: Для окна - вы имеете в виду для самого главного виджета в окне, у которого родитель - `nullptr`?

Comment: @LNK, да, за остальные виджеты отвечают их родители

Comment: И память освободится, всё удалится, если я вызову `close();`? Просто сейчас попробовал закрыть окно, а потом обратится к его потомкам(вызвать метод `show()` и `resize()`), которые должны были быть удалены(чтобы проверить удалились ли потомки). На экран ничего не выводится, но процесс остается запущен, хотя ни одного видимого окна нет. Отсюда возникли сомнения.

Comment: @LNK, когда уничтожается родитель, то он уничтожает всех потомков. Виджет верхнего уровня(окно) родителя не имеет, но благодаря атрибуту `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` оно самоуничтожится при закрытии. Если сомневаетесь, можете взять [этот класс](http://pastebin.com/2Q6u1EXe), написать в конце конструктора какого-нибудь окна `new Watcher(this);` и убедится, что все работает

Comment: А что должно произойти, если обратится к потомку, после того как удален родитель?

Comment: @LNK, если перефразировать ваш вопрос, то получится "Что будет, если обратится к удаленному объекту?". Ответ - Undefined Behavior. Программа может нормально продолжить работать, может вылететь с ошибкой, может заполнить всю имеющуюся память нулями, может отформатировать жесткий диск. Короче, при обращении к удаленным объектам произойти может все что угодно, и это будет в рамках стандарта.

Answer (score 3):

Виджет-родитель при уничтожении автоматически удалит своих потомков.

> When QObjects are created on the heap (i.e., created with new), a tree
>   can be constructed from them in any order, and later, the objects in
>   the tree can be destroyed in any order. When any QObject in the tree
>   is deleted, if the object has a parent, the destructor automatically
>   removes the object from its parent. **If the object has children, the
>   destructor automatically deletes each child.** No QObject is deleted
>   twice, regardless of the order of destruction.

[Object Trees & Ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)

*Другими словами если у вас что-то отображается в окне, то достаточно удалить виджет окна, об остальном позаботится система объектных иерархий Qt.*

Comment: То есть если я просто закрою окно через слот `close()`, все удалится правильно и так?

Comment: @LNK Должен быть вызван деструктор. Это произойдет, если вы последуете совету нагнетателя.